# Create a List that contain each Line of a File

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file and create a list with each line read from the file.

```
   i=0
   List=[""]
   for Line in inFile:
      List[i]=Line.split(",")
      i+=1
   print List
```

But this sample code gives me an error because of the `i+=1` saying that `index is out of range`.
What's my problem here? How can I write the code in order to increment my list with every new Line in the InFile?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It's a lot easier than that:

```
List = open("filename.txt").readlines()
```

This returns a list of each line in the file.

Comment: WoooW Just perfect! It worked. Btw imagine that was not a file... But i wnat to creat a dynamic list... How can I append an element on it? like if was an arrayList?

ty so much

Comment: The append method will do the trick.  For example: xs.append(line)

Comment: what about closing the file ?

Comment: No need to close it, python handles that automatically when the file goes out of scope.

Comment: Is there any way to strip the "/n" from the list generated ?

Comment: this is legacy code, right? it wont let me do this as `with open`

Answer (score 69):

I did it this way

```
lines_list = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
```

Every line comes with its end of line characters (\n\r); this way the characters are removed.

Comment: Thanks, this removes the newlines as I had expected from the accepted answer :) +1 for you

Answer (score 11):

```
my_list = [line.split(',') for line in open("filename.txt")]
```

Comment: I fear jumping into a list comprehension for someone still trying to understand basic python might be a bit large of a step.  :)

Comment: Dustin is right, however orip offered the most correct answer to the question.

Comment: I really like this method. However, at the end of each list, a `\n` is printed next to the last value on the line. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 10):

Please read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  You're swaying pretty far from python conventions.

If you want a list of lists of each line split by comma, I'd do this:

```
l = []
for line in in_file:
    l.append(line.split(','))
```

You'll get a newline on each record.  If you don't want that:

```
l = []
for line in in_file:
    l.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you also want to strip whitespace at beginning and end of each line, you can map the string strip function to the list returned by readlines:

```
map(str.strip, open('filename').readlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

A file is *almost* a list of lines.  You can trivially use it in a **for** loop.

```
myFile= open( "SomeFile.txt", "r" )
for x in myFile:
    print x
myFile.close()
```

Or, if you want an actual list of lines, simply create a list from the file.

```
myFile= open( "SomeFile.txt", "r" )
myLines = list( myFile )
myFile.close()
print len(myLines), myLines
```

You can't do `someList[i]` to put a *new* item at the end of a list.  You must do `someList.append(i)`.

Also, *never* start a simple variable name with an uppercase letter.  `List` confuses folks who know Python.

Also, *never* use a built-in name as a variable.  `list` is an existing data type, and using it as a variable confuses folks who know Python.

Comment: How can I leanr about python coding standards?

Thanks, i didn't know you use varaibable names in lowercase... any special reason for that?

Ty

Comment: While you're on conventions, PEP8 also has something to say about spaces inside of parentheses.  :)

Comment: See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names

Comment: @Dustin: well aware of space-in-parenthesis recommendation in PEP8.  After 3 decades of spaces in ()'s, I'm not going to change.

Comment: @Federico People who read your code and stop to think about why some parts look different from the rest of the code. :)  e.g. what's special about the len() call that makes it consistent with PEP8, but inconsistent with the lines above it? If you don't care, just follow the conventions. :)

Comment: @Dustin: Yes, trivial spacing inconsistencies are inconsistent.  I've seen so much code that simply doesn't work in the first place.  I feel that "working" trumps "consistent spacing".  If spacing leads to difficulty understanding, then there are larger problems to solve first.

Answer (score 1):

f.readlines() returns a list that contains each line as an item in the list

if you want eachline to be split(",") you can use list comprehensions

```
[ list.split(",") for line in file ]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### ... Also If you want to get rid of `\n`

In case the items on your list are with \n and you want to get rid of them:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    list= f.read().splitlines()
```